# In Linux in C/C++ how to determine filesystem type of a mounted or unmounted partition

Tags: c++, linux, mount

`# blkid /dev/sdX` gives the filesystem type of the partition whether mounted or unmounted. How can I do it from C/C++ with out invoking a system call and parsing the out put? How can I do it programatically? Is there any `blkid-dev` package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You always can use the `blkid` libraries (for ubuntu it's as easy as installing libblkid-dev). And for the real usage see: https://github.com/fritzone/sinfonifry/blob/master/plugins/disk_status/client/disk_status.cpp (sorry for advertising code from my own repository, but it has exactly this functionality developed there). And do not forget, that you will need to run the application with sudo in order to have full access to the disk.

Answer (score 2):

For **mounted** partition, instead of reading /proc/self/mounts, you can do that (assuming you know the path where the partition is mounted):

```
#include <sys/vfs.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/magic.h>

static const struct {
    unsigned long magic;
    const char   *type;
} types[] = {
    {EXT4_SUPER_MAGIC, "ext4"},
    {TMPFS_MAGIC, "tmpfs"},
};


const char *get_type(unsigned long magic) {
    static const char * unkown="unkown";
    unsigned int i;

    for (i=0; i < sizeof(types)/sizeof(types[0]); i++)
        if (types[i].magic == magic)
            return types[i].type;

    return unkown;
}

void main() {

    struct statfs buf;

    statfs("/", &buf);
    printf("/ is %s\n", get_type((unsigned long)buf.f_type));

    statfs("/tmp", &buf);
    printf("/tmp is %s\n", get_type((unsigned long)buf.f_type));    
}
```

In my case it displays:

```
/ is ext4
/tmp is tmpfs
```

For more details see

```
man statfs
```

You can obviously add all the types you need. They are listed by the statfs manpage.
It is said that statfs is deprecated, by I don't know of another call that would return the filesystem type.

Answer (score 0):

For mounted partitions, your C++ program could read sequentially and parse the `/proc/self/mounts` pseudo-file, see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

For *unmounted* partitions, they could contain anything (including no file system at all, or swap data, or raw data - e.g. for some database system). So the question may even be meaningless. You might `popen` some `file -s` command.

You should study the source code of `/bin/mount` since it is free software (and it does similar things for the `auto` case). You may want to use [libmagic(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/libmagic.3.html) (which is used by [file(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) command)

Comment: actually I want to find filesystem type to mount the partition so that I can specify it in `mount` function :)

Comment: You are re-inventing the `mount` command with `auto` type. Why can't you use that command?

Comment: I don wanna use a system call. Can i specify `auto` in `mount` function?

Comment: No, you cannot. But this is the case for using `system(3)` function on `/bin/mount`; you could study its source code -of `/bin/mount` - and see how it is done.

Comment: n also I wanna use `ntfs-3g`. So `auto` didn't strike me a good option.

Comment: OK. May b src code for `mount` shows me a way to determine `fs` type.

Comment: mount(8) is a setuid root executable, in general you can't do this in your own program unless it's running as root or also setuid.

Comment: But the OP wants to call the [mount(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) syscall which already requires root privilege.